# How can I return out of a node callback to mongo and redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, return

I think I'm getting confused with the callback, but I have the following code, and I'm trying to return `newpost_template` when the subject name is invalid.  I think my logic is correct, but it's not returning.  It's passing right through.  It works perfectly fine and renders `newpost_template` when there is `!title`.   Any advice is welcome, thanks.

This works:

```
if (!title) {
    var errors = "Post must contain a title";
    return res.render("newpost_template", {
        subject: title,
        username: req.username,
        body: req.body,
        tags: req.tags,
        errors: errors
    });
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
users.findAllSubjectNames(title, req.username, res, req, function(err, doc) {
    "use strict"
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log('doc');
    console.log(doc);

    if (doc === null) {
        console.log('this shows');
        var errors = "Subject name already taken!";
        console.log('this also shows');

        //return res.redirect(" / newpost ") 
        return res.render("newpost_template ", {
            subject: title,
            username: req.username,
            body: req.body,
            tags: req.tags,
            errors: errors
        });
        console.log('this doesnt show');
    }

});

this.findAllSubjectNames = function(title, user, res, req, callback) {
    "use strict";
    users.find({}, {
        "teacher.subject ": 1
    }).toArray(function(err, result) {
        "use strict ";
        if (err) return callback(err, null);

        console.log('result');

        for (var r = 0; r < result.length; r++) {
            for (var t = 0; t < result[r].teacher.length; t++) {
                if (result[r].teacher[t].subject == title && result[r]._id != user) {
                    console.log('INVALID!');
                    return callback(err, null);
                    //return res.redirect(" / newpost ")
                }
            }
        }
        return callback(err, result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Any error / debug messages?

Comment: @dopplesoldner Nope.  I think I may not fully understand the async nature.  There is a `res.redirect(/)` at the end of `users.findAllSubjectNames` thats not shown above.  That takes effect, and the `res.render("newpost_template"...` does not even though doc returns as null.  Is it possible that by the time it does, its too late and the `res.redirect` has already executed?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I had to put the redirect and res.render in an if else clause so only one would execute and only after doc returned.  I also had to separate it into it's own function.

```
 users.findAllSubjectNames(title, req.username, function(err, doc){
    "use strict"
    if(err) return next(err);

    //return res.redirect("/newpost") //res.render("newpost_template", {subject:title, username:req.username, body:req.body, tags:req.tags, errors:errors});
    if(doc === null){
        var errors = "Subject name already taken!";

        return res.render("newpost_template", {subject:title, username:req.username, body:req.body.body, tags:req.tags, errors:errors});
    } else {
        classNumber(title, req, res, next);
        return res.redirect("/profile");    
    }
 });
```